# Vectorize a function to get closest date from a list of dates

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

**I cant use external libraries other than pandas or numpy**

If I had a dataframe like

```
import pandas as pd
d = pd.DataFrame({'purchase_date':[datetime(2022,1,5),datetime(2022,12,10)],'shop_visits':[[datetime(2021,1,4),datetime(2022,1,6),datetime(2022,1,7)],[datetime(2022,5,30),datetime(2022,9,30),datetime(2022,12,10)]]})
```

| purchase_dt | shop_visits |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-05 | [2022-01-04,2022-01-06,2022-01-07] |
| 2022-12-10 | [2022-05-30,2022-09-30,2022-12-10] |

I would need a function that returns 2022-01-06 for the first row and 2022-12-10 for the second, because both are the closest dates on the list after purchase_dt.

I have a function with apply already that does the min with my own lambda key, but its taking too long and I want to vectorize:

```
d.apply(lambda x: min([d for d in x['shop_visits'] if d >= x['purchase_date']],key=lambda d: d-x['purchase_date']),axis=1)
```

The thing is that I am not sure if this can be done using numpy.

Comment: added a solution, does it work?

Answer (score 2):

here is one way to accomplish it

explode shop-visits, create a df2, where purchase_date is same or less than shop_visit. finally do a groupby to choose the first result

```
df2=df.explode('shop_visits')
df2=df2[df2['purchase_date']<=df2['shop_visits']]
df2[df2.groupby(['purchase_date']).cumcount().eq(0)]
```

OR

```py
df2=df.explode('shop_visits')
df2[df2['purchase_date']<=df2['shop_visits']].groupby('purchase_date').first().reset_index()
```

```
    purchase_date   shop_visits
0   2022-01-05      2022-01-06
1   2022-12-10      2022-12-10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```py
left = d.drop(columns=["shop_visits"]).reset_index()
right = d["shop_visits"].explode().sort_values().to_frame().reset_index()

pd.merge_asof(
    left,
    right,
    by="index",
    left_on="purchase_date",
    right_on="shop_visits",
    direction="forward",
).drop(columns=["index"])
```

---

Here's a faster version without `merge_asof`:

```py
tmp = (
    # Extract purchase_date and shop_visits
    d[["purchase_date", "shop_visits"]]
    # Explode shop_visits
    .explode("shop_visits")
    # Reset index so we can align using this index later
    .reset_index()
    # Since we only care about visits on or after the purchase_date,
    # filter out the rest
    .query("purchase_date <= shop_visits")
    # Sort by the original index and shop visit date
    .sort_values(["index", "shop_visits"])
    # For each index, keep only the first visit
    .drop_duplicates("index")
)

# Set the original index back on tmp and so that we can
# easily align it with the original dataframe
d["first_visit_after_purchase"] = tmp.set_index("index")[["shop_visits"]]

# Note that some first_visit_after_purchase may be NaN due
# to our query condition
```

Took 7 seconds on my ancient Mac when `d` has 1M rows and 10 visits for each row.

The processing time grows linearly with the total number of shop visits (`len(d["shop_visits"].explode())`).

Comment: Looks great but in my real example I have other columns that the date to join by which are strings like city,etc.. not sure how that would work.

Comment: `direction="nearest"` will merge with the nearest date - not the nearest that is greater than.

Comment: @MMM you can tweak the left dataframe to have all columns but `shop_visits`. See my updated answer

Comment: @CodeDifferent thanks a lot but I am still looking for vectorizing, for speed performance, the solution you proposed is great but still slow

Comment: (a) What is the shape of your dataframe? (b) How many `purchase_date`s are there after being exploded (you can find out with `len(right)`)